# Error in right diagonal dots in xymatrix

Tags: xymatrix

Compiling the following tex lines

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\def\rddots#1{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^{#1}}}}    

\begin{document}

\[ 
\xymatrix@-1.75pc{
\overset{}{\bullet} & & \overset{}{\bullet} 
& &\ldots & & 
\overset{}{\bullet} & & \overset{}{\bullet}
& & \overset{}{\bullet} & &\overset{}{\bullet} 
& &\ldots & &  
\overset{}{\bullet} & &\overset{}{\bullet}   \\ 
& \ar@{-}[ul] \overset{}{\bullet} \ar@{-}[ur] 
& & & & & & \ar@{-}[ul] \overset{}{\bullet} \ar@{-}[ur] 
& & & & \ar@{-}[ul] \overset{}{\bullet} \ar@{-}[ur]
& & & & & & 
\ar@{-}[ul] \overset{}{\bullet} \ar@{-}[ur] &   \\ 
&  & \ddots & & & & &  \vdots & &  & & 
\vdots & & & & & \rddots
& &  \\ 
&  & & \overset{}{\bullet}& & & & 
\overset{}{\bullet} 
& & & & \overset{}{\bullet}& & & & 
\overset{}{\bullet} 
& & &   \\ 
&  & & & &  \ar@{-}[ull]\overset{}{\bullet}\ar@{-}[urr] 
& & & & & & & & \ar@{-}[ull]\overset{}{\bullet} \ar@{-}[urr]
& & & & &  \\ 
&  & & & & & & & &  \ar@{-}[ullll] \overset{}{\bullet}
\ar@{-}[urrrr]
& & & & & & & & & \\  }
\] 

\end{document}
```

produces this tree

[image: tree]

but I am getting an error

```
! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
<argument> ...veryentry@ \cdot ^{\cdot ^{\cdot ^{&
                                                  }}} 
l.34     & & & & & & & & & \\  }
```

and I am not sure how to resolve it. The problem is coming from `rddots`. Any assistance to address this would be appreciated.

Comment: This page could be interesting http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing that command to obtain the dots, rotate the normal `\ddots`. Load `graphicx` and make use of `\rotatebox{90}{$\ddots$}` to rotate by 90 degrees. Observe that $\ddots$ is passed in math mode since the second argument of `\rotatebox{}{}` does not imply to math mode.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\rddots}{\rotatebox{90}{$\ddots$}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{graphicx} % added
\begin{document}

\[ 
\xymatrix@-1.75pc{
\overset{}{\bullet} & & \overset{}{\bullet} 
& &\ldots & & 
\overset{}{\bullet} & & \overset{}{\bullet}
& & \overset{}{\bullet} & &\overset{}{\bullet} 
& &\ldots & &  
\overset{}{\bullet} & &\overset{}{\bullet}   \\ 
& \ar@{-}[ul] \overset{}{\bullet} \ar@{-}[ur] 
& & & & & & \ar@{-}[ul] \overset{}{\bullet} \ar@{-}[ur] 
& & & & \ar@{-}[ul] \overset{}{\bullet} \ar@{-}[ur]
& & & & & & 
\ar@{-}[ul] \overset{}{\bullet} \ar@{-}[ur] &   \\ 
&  & \ddots & & & & &  \vdots & &  & & 
\vdots & & & & & \rddots
& &  \\ 
&  & & \overset{}{\bullet}& & & & 
\overset{}{\bullet} 
& & & & \overset{}{\bullet}& & & & 
\overset{}{\bullet} 
& & &   \\ 
&  & & & &  \ar@{-}[ull]\overset{}{\bullet}\ar@{-}[urr] 
& & & & & & & & \ar@{-}[ull]\overset{}{\bullet} \ar@{-}[urr]
& & & & &  \\ 
&  & & & & & & & &  \ar@{-}[ullll] \overset{}{\bullet}
\ar@{-}[urrrr]
& & & & & & & & & \\  }
\] 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think also you can replace `\overset{}{\bullet}` by simply `\bullet`.

Comment: I agree, but I left them in there since I plan to share this code with someone else, and in case that person wants to label the vertices.

Comment: Also, you can use `\ar@{..}[rr]` instead of dots, to produce some dotted arrow.